# Java: MQTT MessageProducerSupport to Flux

Tags: spring-integration, mqtt, reactor

I have a simple MQTT Client that outputs received messages via `IntegrationFlow`:

```
public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
    DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
    MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
    options.setServerURIs(new String[] { "tcp://test.mosquitto.org:1883" });
    factory.setConnectionOptions(options);
    return factory;
}

public MessageProducerSupport mqttInbound() {
    MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(
            "myConsumer",
            mqttClientFactory(),
            "/test/#");
    adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
    adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
    adapter.setQos(1);
    return adapter;
}

public IntegrationFlow mqttInFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(mqttInbound())
            .transform(p -> p + ", received from MQTT")
            .handle(logger())
            .get();
}

private LoggingHandler logger() {
    LoggingHandler loggingHandler = new LoggingHandler("INFO");
    loggingHandler.setLoggerName("siSample");
    return loggingHandler;
}
```

I need to pipe all received messages into a `Flux` though for further processing.

```
public Flux<String> mqttChannel() {
    ...
    return mqttFlux;
}
```

How can I do that? The loggingHandler receives all messages from the IntegrationFlow. Couldn't my Flux get it's input in a similar fashion - by passing it somehow to IntegrationFlows handle function?

MQTT Example code is take from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/mqtt/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/mqtt/Application.java

Attempt: Following Artem Bilans advise I'm now trying to use `toReactivePublisher` to convert my inbound `IntegrationFlow` to `Flux`.

```
public Flux<String> mqttChannel() {
    Publisher<Message<Object>> flow = IntegrationFlows.from(mqttInbound())
            .toReactivePublisher();
    Flux<String> mqttFlux = Flux.from(flow)
            .log()
            .map(i -> "TESTING: Received a MQTT message");
    return mqttFlux;
}
```

Running the example i get following error:

```
10:14:39.541 [MQTT Call: myConsumer] ERROR o.s.i.m.i.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter - Unhandled exception for GenericMessage [payload=OFF,26.70,65.00,663,-62,192.168.2.100,0.026,25,4,6,7,933,278,27,4,1,0,1580496218,730573600,1800000,1980000,1580496218,730573600,10800000,11880000, headers={mqtt_receivedRetained=true, mqtt_id=0, mqtt_duplicate=false, id=3f7565aa-ff4f-c389-d8a9-712d4f06f1cb, mqtt_receivedTopic=/083B7036697886C41D2DF2FD919143EE/MasterBedroom/Sensor/, mqtt_receivedQos=0, timestamp=1602231279537}]
```

Conclusion: as soon as the first message arrives, it's handled wrong and an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read this doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/reactive-streams.html#reactive-streams

It is not clear what you would like to achieve with that "my flux" and how that could look, but for your current configuration there are a couple of solutions.

You can use a `FluxMessageChannel` which is already a `Publisher`, so you can simply use `Flux.from()` and subscriber to that for consuming data produced by the mentioned `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`.

Another way is to use a `toReactivePublisher()` on the `IntegrationFlowBuilder` to expose the whole flow as a reactive `Publsiher` source. In this case, of course, you can't use the `LoggingHandler` because it is a one-way and makes your flow ending exactly here. You may consider to use a `log()` operator instead though: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-log

By the way the `FluxMessageChannel` is publish-subscribe, so you can have it in the flow for those logs and also have it externally for `Flux.from()` subscription. All the subscribers to this channel are going to get the same message.

Comment: I'm trying to make MQTT channels available as Policy Information Points for the SAPL access control system (sapl.io). The existing implementation expects to receive outside information via Flux subscription. I'll try your ideas tomorrow.

Comment: I think your propositions brought us one step further - we now turned the output into a Flux, but the Flux is not delivering any data to the subscriber. As this is part of an University workshop, we'll work on it until it's solved. I will update this thread with any solutions that we find.