# Java Spring MQTT Subscriber toReactivePublisher()

Tags: spring-integration

I have to convert the message of a mqtt inbound adapter into a Flux. Following the advice of Artem Bilan in [Java: MQTT MessageProducerSupport to Flux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64267888/java-mqtt-messageproducersupport-to-flux)
I used the toReactivePublisher(). However, I get an Error:

```
ERROR - Unhandled exception for GenericMessage ... nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=10, headers={mqtt_receivedRetained=false, mqtt_id=51, mqtt_duplicate=false, ..
```

My Mqtt Client factory and adapter is taken from the spring integration reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mqtt.html#mqtt

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringMqttClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, MqttException {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringMqttClient.class).run(args);

@Bean
public String topic() {
    return "my/test/topic";
}

@Bean
public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
    DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
    MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
    options.setServerURIs(new String[] { "tcp://localhost:1883" }); 
    options.setUserName("SpringClient");
    options.setPassword("SpringClient".toCharArray());
    factory.setConnectionOptions(options);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public MessageProducerSupport mqttInbound() {
    MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("SpringClient", mqttClientFactory(),
            topic());
    adapter.setCompletionTimeout(10000);
    adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
    adapter.setQos(1);
    adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public Flux<Message<byte[]>> mqttInFlow(MessageProducerSupport adapter) {
    return Flux.from(
            IntegrationFlows.from(adapter).transform(p -> p + ", received from MQTT").log().toReactivePublisher());
}
```

As soon as I exchange the Bean mqttInFlow() with a handler() from the Spring Integration Reference Guide it works fine; however I need a Flux, not only a String. What's wrong on the mqttInFlow() Bean? How can I create a Flux with the toReactivePublisher() Method?

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    return new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {
            log.info("SpringClient got message: " + message.getPayload());
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot do `Flux.from(IntegrationFlows.from())`. The framework won't see that `IntegrationFlow` for parsing and proper processing. The `@Bean` must return an `IntegrtionFlow` or a result of that `toReactivePublisher()`. No extra wrapping to the `Flux` - you lose connection with an `ApllicationContext`.
2. The `mqttInputChannel` is a `DirectChannel` and if you use that `@ServiceActivator` and point to the same `mqttInbound` from the `IntegrationFlow`, you end up with a couple round-robin subscribers to that `MessageProducerSupport`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#channel-implementations-directchannel
3. If you do a reactive, on demand, consumption, you must not have that `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` to be started automatically. `setAutoStartup(false)` must be there.
4. When you get (inject) a `Publsiher<Message<byte[]>>` bean, only there you wrap it into a `Flux` for your possible processing.

So, the solution for you might be like this:

```
@Bean
public MessageProducerSupport mqttInbound() {
    MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter = new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("SpringClient", mqttClientFactory(),
            topic());
    adapter.setCompletionTimeout(10000);
    adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
    adapter.setQos(1);
    adapter.setAutoStartup(false);
    return adapter;
}


@Bean
public Publisher<Message<byte[]>> mqttInFlow(MessageProducerSupport adapter) {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(adapter)
              .transform(p -> p + ", received from MQTT")
              .log()
              .toReactivePublisher();
}
```

Then you have to do like this in the target place where you are going to use `Flux`:

```
@Autowired
MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter;

@Autowired
Publisher<Message<byte[]>> mqttInFlow;

...

Flux<Message<byte[]>> flux = 
        Flux.from(mqttInFlow)
            .doOnSubscribe(s -> adapter.start())
            .doOnTerminate(mqttInbound::stop);
```

See some similar solution in the Stream Applications project: https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/blob/main/functions/supplier/mqtt-supplier/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/fn/supplier/mqtt/MqttSupplierConfiguration.java

Comment: I have decided to revise the logic and came up with solution like this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3657.

Comment: You cannot create an adapter manually. As well as `IntegrationFlow`. Well, you can, of course, if you use an `IntegrationFlowContext`, but sounds like it is not your case.  Please, consider to raise a new SO question with much more info.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your comment. Thank you for your help. Ok, I will raise a new SO in case I am not able to get it working.